# How to print all the defined variables in emacs?

Tags: emacs

M-x < TAB > prints all the defined functions.

To check a variable is defined or not evaluating the following expression,
(boundp 'variable-name) C-x C-e will print t if the variable-name is defined else nill.

How to print all the defined variables in emacs.

Comment: What do you mean by "M-x prints all the defined functions"? `M-x` prompts you to enter the name of an interactive command, and then executes it. (And if you mean you can press TAB to see the auto-completion list... well, that's just the interactive functions, not "all the defined functions".)

Comment: I posted as M-x <TAB> which is not displayed, i edited it to M-x < TAB \>, which works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you want to do with a full list of symbols, since the way in which `M-x` displays function names is somewhat specialized.

Assuming that you want to programmatically obtain a list of all defined symbols, here's how `auto-complete.el` does it:

```
(loop for x being the symbols
    if (boundp x)
    collect (symbol-name x))
```

Note that you can also enter `M-x describe-var RET`, and then press `TAB` to get a sorted completion list of all symbols.

Comment: Well, what you probably really want, then, is `M-x customize-group RET org RET`.

Comment: Thanks for that, it definitely helps me in understanding the org mode example configurations.

Answer (score 7):

Extrapolating (heavily!) what is being asked for, here is a way to get a pretty-printed alist of all buffer-local variables with their values. This is very convenient for finding out why for instance a mode isn't behaving the way one expects.

To get this listing, do:

```
M-x pp-eval-expression RET (buffer-local-variables) RET
```

Relevant portions from this list can be added almost verbatim to a `.dir-locals.el` file for use with multiple files.

Answer (score 5):

I presume `(apropos-variable "." t)` would show you all the variables defined at that point in time.

edit: I presumed wrongly, it would seem.

Interestingly, this actually shows me significantly fewer results than the auto-completions from `describe-var`.

Can anyone shed light on that?

e.g. the differences between these, when `winner-mode` has been enabled:

- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `winner-` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `winner-` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

edit 2: Ah... it looks like apropos may ignore any symbol which lacks a documentation string.

If it's possible, I suggest reassigning the accepted answer.