# How to write .emacs from Emacs when I've deleted .emacs

Tags: emacs

I have Emacs open but accidentally I've deleted the .emacs file it read when it started. This represents about 15 years of tweaking. (I know, I know, backups.)

Is there a way to get Emacs to write out the .emacs file I've deleted?

I wouldn't normally ask such a lame question on SO but I know I only have a day or so before this Emacs session ends.

Comment: So do you have a buffer open with .emacs?

Comment: Heh, no, I'm not *that* lame.

Comment: Zev's answer was your best bet, sounds like you're SOL.

Comment: Seriously Steve, get it into version control as soon as you get it back, or (sad face) have to rebuild it from scratch. You could probably get `customize` to throw out some settings for you, and also check loaded libraries (that'll take a bit of doing!) ... just a thought.

Comment: I recommend Dropbox or something similar for this

Comment: Interesting question; bleak situation.  *Fifteen years* with no backup?  You are an oddball among oddballs (i.e., emacs users).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ayckoster suggests, you might try a file recovery or forensics tool like [The Sleuth Kit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/).  Or, and this may seem crazy, if you're on a Unix-like system, you could search through the raw disk device (on the Mac I'm currently on, that would be /dev/rdisk1).  Seriously, several times I've been too lazy to break out a full-blown recovery tool but instead used something like `sudo less -f /dev/rdisk1`, searched for a string I knew was in the file (`global-set-key`, anyone?), and succeeded in recovering the file's original content.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it's the one that actually got me my file back (grepping through /dev/disk0). Many thanks.

Comment: @ajk: +1 to your answer for the "global-set-key", made me laugh for my .emacs is indeed full of that ; ) But that said, I've got copies of my .emacs in several user accounts, on several computers, in Mercurial, in my GMail account, on DropBox, etc.  I mean, the OP is plain sick for never having backed'up that file.  Plain sick.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Emacs' backup feature turned on, you should have a copy of your next-to-last .emacs file in ~/.emacs~. If so, just rename that one to ".emacs" and you will have the .emacs file with all but your latest changes. Even if you don't currently have backups enabled, you might still have a substantial chunk of your .emacs file in the last backup on file. You should also look at the  value of the variable "backup-directory-alist" - it specifies location(s) for backup files to be stored if the default (same directory as modified file) isn't used.

Otherwise, how good is your memory... ;-)

EDIT: Since you don't have a backup of your .emacs file but you have a running Emacs instance that was started with that .emacs file, another thing you can do is to save all the custom settings that would have been defined in your .emacs file. To do this, do something like:

```
(setq custom-file "/my/home/directory/.emacs-custom.el")
(custom-save-all)
```

Then, you could create a new .emacs file and add the following lines to it:

```
(setq custom-file "/my/home/directory/.emacs-custom.el")
(load custom-file)
```

That will at least restore some of the custom variable settings that were in your .emacs file.

Comment: Unfortunately I never edit .emacs in Emacs. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer with another suggestion using "custom-save-all".

Comment: I edit it vi. Seriously, I have no idea why. I always open vi for small edits and emacs for developing. Many thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am putting .emacs in source control now :)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs evaluates your .emacs file and afterwards it is closed. So basically you cannot get your .emacs back.

A solution might be to use a file recovery application. The odds of your .emacs being on your hard drive are quite good.

As most such programs cannot deduce the file name or directory name of the deleted file you have to know the content of your .emacs.

Then you can restore all currently deleted files in some folder and recursively search for the contents of your .emacs.

This process might take very long. You have to decide if its worth your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to get Emacs to provide the original .emacs file, but you can certainly interrogate the loaded function and variable symbols, and obtain their values.

This would be rather a lot of work, but I think in theory you should be able to obtain a good chunk of this data in some form or other, if you succeeded in filtering it all down to what you knew was yours.

For evaluated functions, `(symbol-function 'SYMBOL)` will return a (less-readable) definition of the supplied function. You could then use `(fset 'SYMBOL VALUE)`, where VALUE is the result of the call to `symbol-function`, to define that function in a new .emacs file. That would give you an approach for recovering your defined functions.

- http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html
- http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html

You might also look at:
[How to print all the defined variables in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493331/how-to-print-all-the-defined-variables-in-emacs)

This is a *very* incomplete starter, but given time constraints I'm posting and marking it community wiki, if anyone wants to run with it.

A how-to for dumping the state of the application in a reliably restorable fashion would be a great start, if the current session is definitely going to be killed (or even if it's not, actually, to guard against crashing or other mishap).

You could potentially re-tag this with some more general data-recovery type tags, to expand the audience.