# print symbols of emacs in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to print all the symbols in emacs using elisp.

It is possible to test wheather a lisp object is a symbol using symbolp
function. But how to collect all the symbols.

Is it possible to access symbol table of emacs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print all the defined variables in emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493331/how-to-print-all-the-defined-variables-in-emacs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(require 'cl)

(loop for x being the symbols
    if (boundp x)
    collect (symbol-name x))
```

`loop` is a Common Lisp macro, that has been ported to Emacs Lisp as well. It's part of the `cl` package (part of the standard Emacs distribution), that you'll have to `require` to use it.

Another option to consider is probably:

```
(apropos "." t)
```

The `apropos` invokation will take significantly more time to complete, but you'll get more information about the symbols that way.

Comment: i am getting error (void-funtion loop). I am using emacs version 22.1.1 in ubuntu 8.04 64 bit version. Also i checked the emacs lisp reference manual, there is no explanation on function loop. Should i have to install seperate package to get the loop function.

Comment: You'll need to `(require 'cl)` to have `loop`, however emacs22 is a (very?) old emacs. You should consider using emacs24 or at least emacs23.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness, here's how you'd list all of the symbols without using the `cl` package:

Go to a newly-created buffer, and type <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(mapatoms (lambda (s) (insert (symbol-name s) "\n")))`<kbd>RET</kbd>.  That will insert the names of all existing symbols in the buffer, one per line.