# Emacs: list the names of every interactive command

Tags: emacs

i.e. anything that can be run from `M-x`. including any C built-ins, user-defined, etc.

e.g. `list-all-commands`

```
'(... about-emacs ... zap-to-char ...)
```

it must be accessible, given behavior like autocomplete for `M-x`.

from [How to print all the defined variables in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493331/how-to-print-all-the-defined-variables-in-emacs), we can access all symbols:

```
(pp-eval-expression
   (quote (loop for x being the symbols
      if (boundp x)
      collect (symbol-name x))))
```

but most of those are not interactive functions.

EDIT:

*sigh* there is a point, in fact. By sending this list to the speech recognition engine, after tokenizing on the hyphen, and `symbol-name` and whatever, I should be able to speak all but the most strangely-written commands (Dragon NaturallySpeaking is good about that). without this list, recognition accuracy would decrease, and I would have to manually hardcode keyboard shortcuts for any commands I wanted, or deal with constant frustration at misrecognitions.

that is what I need. but, I might also want to write my own autocomplete behavior; or compare the similarity of the names that different modes provide; or to discover new commands that are lexically similar to common commands I use (e.g. using `align-regex` often might suggest `align-entire`); or to analyze any inconsistencies in naming movement through different regions (e.g. `beginning-of-line` versus `up-list`); or I already looked at say `ido`, and wanted to see if there was a standard function to build the data structure it uses to efficiently query; or I feel like benchmarking it; or maybe I'm just curious. there are lots of uses for this.

the whole point of Emacs is that behavior is exposed to the programmer, and not just through the UI.

Can you take back your vote to close now? I think it's not "unclear what I'm asking", and if it is suggest points of clarification.

Comment: What's the point of it? You already have `M-x`.

Comment: I do have `M-x`. I don't have `list-all-commands `. See my edit.

Comment: Are you including commands which are not loaded (or autoloaded) by default? There are a vast number of commands which Emacs will not know about until the library in question has been loaded by some means.

Comment: @phils "runnable" commands, are fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
(let ((cmds  ()))
  (mapatoms (lambda (s) (when (commandp s) (push s cmds))))
  cmds)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a symbol is an interactive command with `commandp`:

```
(pp-eval-expression
 '(loop for x being the symbols
        if (commandp x) collect x))
```

Answer (score 2):

*M-x space* should give you a buffer with a complete list of completions. Use *C-x o* (perhaps multiple times) to switch from the mini-buffer to the completion buffer and copy its contents.

The elisp function doing that completion is found in *simple.el* in the function *read-extended-command*:

```
(completing-read
 (concat (cond
          ((eq current-prefix-arg '-) "- ")
          ((and (consp current-prefix-arg)
                (eq (car current-prefix-arg) 4)) "C-u ")
          ((and (consp current-prefix-arg)
                (integerp (car current-prefix-arg)))
           (format "%d " (car current-prefix-arg)))
          ((integerp current-prefix-arg)
           (format "%d " current-prefix-arg)))
         ;; This isn't strictly correct if `execute-extended-command'
         ;; is bound to anything else (e.g. [menu]).
         ;; It could use (key-description (this-single-command-keys)),
         ;; but actually a prompt other than "M-x" would be confusing,
         ;; because "M-x" is a well-known prompt to read a command
         ;; and it serves as a shorthand for "Extended command: ".
         "M-x ")
 obarray 'commandp t nil 'extended-command-history)))
```

Comment: that's really cool. do you know what provides that? I could then just read it source, and find the function it's calling.

Comment: @sam boosalis: *C-h k M-x* gives: `M-x runs the command execute-extended-command, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function.

It is bound to <execute>, <menu>, M-x.

(execute-extended-command PREFIXARG &optional COMMAND-NAME)
` ... I'ld search in the sources with that name.

Comment: My Emacs (`GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)`) says it `runs the command execute-extended-command, which is an interactive built-in function in 'C source code'`. it doesn't have a link to the source, and I don't know if the C would make any sense.

Comment: @sam boosalis: One moment. Installing elisp sources. Trying to find the function.

Comment: @sam boosalis: I added the lisp source referenced in my emacs 24.4.1 on debian linux. I cannot tell you if it will work in mac emacs