# What "local rules" have been set in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, smie

I have been trying to solve a `sh-mode` indentation issue in Emacs (I get a double indent after a `then`) and found that I can set the indentation by hand and then run `C-c >` to automatically configure the indentation.

However, this configuration only applies to my current session and I can't seem to find any variables that have been modified as a result of the auto-configuration.  (It worked though: the indentation is consistently what I want.)  When it has run, it says "Local rules set" but doesn't tell me *what* local rules have been set.

And of course, when I restart Emacs, the local configuration is lost and I have to run the auto-config command again.

I've found a number of questions on this site about listing variables and their values, but I can't find out how to list ones that have only been changed for the current session.  I even used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27813441/1999993) to dump variables before and after running the `C-c >` command and comparing the output; nothing obviously different.

So I suppose my question is twofold:

1. If session variables are what's meant by "local rules" then how do I find out which ones were set?
2. If "local rules" means something else, then what is that and how can I somehow transfer those changes to my `~/.emacs` file?

Comment: I don't speak keyboard shortcut as well as others, but I am familiar with how to look up the name of the function that gets triggered.  `C-h k C-c >` aka `M-x describe-key RET C-c >`  Then, you can use the mouse or enter key in the `*Help*` buffer to visit the source code or you can type `M-x find-function` and see what is happening and start tracing backwards.  This is probably more practical than inspecting all buffer-local variables.  Perhaps the tracing begins with the function `sh-learn-buffer-indent` inside `sh-script.el`?

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report, to improve the "*Local rules set*" message: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Richard Wiseman  -- a grep of the Emacs source code for "Local rules set" leads us to the function `smie-config-guess`, which contains a doc-string that states:  "*Try and figure out this buffer's indentation settings.  To save the result for future sessions, use `smie-config-save`.*"

Comment: Sorry @lawlist, perhaps I should have said that was the function I was running via the `C-c >` shortcut.  I did actually know that because I ran the function directly initially but it told me there was a shortcut I could use instead!  And thanks for the `smie-config-save` suggestion; I did notice that contained the same text but decided it was unrelated to `sh-script.el`.

Comment: Thanks @Drew for the suggestion.  I may have now filed a bug report...  Or it may have failed.  I completed the information, pressed `C-c C-c` and (because I didn't have an SMTP server to use) chose to send to my email client, and then ... nothing.  Feels like it failed.

Comment: Hm. If you chose `mail client` at the prompt asking how to send it, then it should have opened a new mail message using your email client. There you would see text in the message body telling you to select it and use Paste to replace it with the message that you wrote in Emacs. IOW, the message you write in Emacs gets put on the clipboard, and you then paste it into a mail-client message (which should be displayed automatically). (If this doesn't work, please file a bug about this too. ;-)) You can also file a bug by just submitting mail to `bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`.

Comment: Yes, you filed the bug report OK. You should have received a confirmation mail message. The bug is #[24848](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24848).

Comment: Thanks @Drew, I actually resubmitted the bug manually (rather than trying to do it via Emacs).  I had to rewrite it but it seemed worthwhile.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm more confused.  I don't know what (if anything) has changed, but now when I modify the indentation and ask it to learn it, it now says "Nothing to change".  This is bizarre because when I then press TAB on the (currently correctly indented) line, it reverts to the old, incorrect (i.e. double) indentation!  So I delete two spaces so it looks right, and then try `C-c >` again - and it once again says "Nothing to change"!  I even restarted Emacs in case that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the result depends on your version of Emacs, but with a recent version, this is handled by SMIE, so the personal settings are kept in the `smie-config` variable.

The local settings in use in the current buffer are kept in an internal variable (`smie-config--buffer-local`).  You can move them over to `smie-config` and save them into your `~/.emacs` by calling `smie-config-save`.

One more detail: `smie-config-save` doesn't in itself save the settings to `~/.emacs`.  It only transfers them from the transient buffer-local variable `smie-config--buffer-local` to the global `smie-config` variable which is under the control of *Customize* and can have be saved to your `~/.emacs` via something like `M-x customize-save-customized`.  This should arguably be improved in `smie-config-save`.  I suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug` to ask for this improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1.  I've run the `C-c >` command (and confirmed that the new indentation works) and have checked the value of `smie-config` but it's `nil` with state "STANDARD".  Does that mean my Emacs isn't using SMIE?

Comment: I added more details about where the buffer-local and transient settings are kept.

Comment: Thanks.  That does make it clearer, but doesn't seem to have any effect.  My `~/.emacs` file doesn't mention `smie` at all, so my attempt to save it can't have worked.  And now I've got the problem where `C-c >` doesn't even report "Local rules set" (see my comment above) so I can't even try to save any more.

Comment: It's been a while but this is still irritating me!  I've managed to get the smie config to save; my `.emacs` file now contains a line: `'(smie-config (quote ((sh-mode (2 :elem basic 4)))))` but unfortunately this has no impact upon `js-mode`!  So it looks like the smie config is separate from the `js-mode` config.  When `js-learn-buffer-indent` says "Local rules set" it does seem to mean smie rules (since `smie-config-save` does note that there has been a change), but saving them apparently has no effect. And there has been no movement on the bug I reported 295 days ago either. :-(

Comment: @RichardWiseman: js-mode doesn't use SMIE, so your problem with js-mode is yet different :-(  As for the bug-report, could you remind me its bug-number?

Comment: The bug number is [24848](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24848) but in that discussion, it has been suggested that SMIE might well be used for `js-mode` these days.  I've certainly found that using `smie-config-guess` has the same impact as `sh-learn-buffer-indent` (i.e. it works in the current buffer) but sadly also seems impossible to save for future sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an incomplete workaround than an answer, but it's a start!

The idea is to trigger sh-learn-buffer-indent as soon as a shell script is loaded.  Add the following to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'sh-set-shell-hook 'sh-learn-buffer-indent)
```

A couple of important notes:

1. It assumes that your shell script is already correctly formatted when it's loaded.
2. It can be slow for large files.

(This is apparently mentioned in `sh-script.el` and was brought to my attention by Noam Postavsky via the [bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24848) I filed.)